# Apache 2.4 not proxying via mod_rewrite using rules that work on 2.2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I've installed Apache 2.4 on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS box and added my site and everything works fine except a proxy rewrite rule for some images. The rule I have set up is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /images/here/(.*)$ http://my.site.com/images/here/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

However when I try to access a file say:

```
http://other.site.com/images/here/image.jpg
```

I get a 404 error in the browser. I switched on rewrite logging and in the log it would appear that it is matching the rules and applying the proxy correctly:

```
[Wed Sep 23 09:47:16.387531 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29527:tid 139709285484288] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.0.5.61:51099] 10.0.5.61 - - [other.site.com/sid#7f109fe93400][rid#7f109fe070a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/here/image.jpg
[Wed Sep 23 09:47:16.387700 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 29527:tid 139709285484288] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.0.5.61:51099] 10.0.5.61 - - [other.site.com/sid#7f109fe93400][rid#7f109fe070a0/initial] applying pattern '/images/here/(.*)$' to uri '/images/here/image.jpg'
[Wed Sep 23 09:47:16.387736 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29527:tid 139709285484288] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.0.5.61:51099] 10.0.5.61 - - [other.site.com/sid#7f109fe93400][rid#7f109fe070a0/initial] rewrite '/images/here/image.jpg' -> 'http://my.site.com/images/here/image.jpg'
[Wed Sep 23 09:47:16.387748 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 29527:tid 139709285484288] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.0.5.61:51099] 10.0.5.61 - - [other.site.com/sid#7f109fe93400][rid#7f109fe070a0/initial] forcing proxy-throughput with http://my.site.com/images/here/image.jpg
[Wed Sep 23 09:47:16.387757 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 29527:tid 139709285484288] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.0.5.61:51099] 10.0.5.61 - - [other.site.com/sid#7f109fe93400][rid#7f109fe070a0/initial] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://my.site.com/images/here/image.jpg [OK]
```

I've checked that mod_rewrite, mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are all enabled an they are. I've also tried accessing the image using `curl` and `wget` from the server and it can get them image fine, so it is not a network issue with the server not managing to access the image.

This same rule works fine on Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6 and 7 boxes.

I'm at a loss now as to why it is not working. Maybe something else is required in 2.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two small issues:

Apache2.4 needs a different string-start anchor:

```
RewriteRule /images/here/
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule ^images/here/
```

And your flags might cause issues:

- [P] already implies [L], see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p
- [QSA] might cause problems with your proxy, remove it altogether unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this still did work. The only thing I can get to work is removing all the flags and then it 302's to the image instead, which is workable for me, however I would really like to understand why the proxy doesn't work.